# Is there a function in LUA to substitute values on a string but keep part of the original value?

Tags: string, lua, concatenation, substitution

I'm trying to get a string like:
`"1d6+1d12-1d20+5"`

And turn it into this: `"rolar('1d6')+rolar('1d12')-rolar('1d20')+5"`

The gist being that the `xdy` should be replaced with `rolar('xdy')` but with the original value in that part. I've been trying to do this with `string:gsub` but haven't been able to mantain the original xdy value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for this is simply "one or more digits, then the letter `d`, then again one or more digits". Replace this with the capture wrapped in a string literal & func call to `rolar`.

```lua
str:gsub("%d+d%d+", "rolar('%1')")
```

where `str` is your string - for example:

```lua
> ("1d6+1d12-1d20+5"):gsub("%d+d%d+", "rolar('%1')")
rolar('1d6')+rolar('1d12')-rolar('1d20')+5  3
```

(the second return value, `3`, is the number of replacements performed by `gsub`; you presumably don't need it)

I assume your next step will be to `loadstring` this code in order to evaluate it. **Be very careful when doing so**; at the very least use a sandboxed environment (i.e., an environment without access to any global variables, ideally even with a temporarily changed string metatable). This won't protect against even simple DoS attacks like `while 1 do end`, but at least it doesn't make it trivial to wipe your filesystem.

Comment: I'm trying to make a macro for an online tabletop RPG software, since it currently only allows for simple math equations with the die, so I think it is a sandbox environment(?) . Thanks a lot for the concern and help.

That being said, it seems the ```$1``` part doesn't really work on the software... Besides, when I run it on Lua Demo, it returns ```rolar('$1')``` without the original ```rolar('xdy')``` part it substituted. Is this a callback function of some sort?

Comment: @thirteen It's %1 not $1.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I've tried this again and now it absolutely works. Thanks a lot to both of you, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you're positive that the input will always be in a configuration like that, you can do this with gsub, using capture groups (parentheses around string patterns).

```
str:gsub("(%d+d%d+)", function(roll) return "rolar('"..roll.."')" end)
```

The captured pattern `%d+d%d` is passed to the function you give to gsub as an argument, and you can then re-insert back into the string with whatever modifications you want.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the pattern: If there are no captures, the entire pattern will be captured.